# Redirect ALL packets from eth1 & eth2 through a SOCKS proxy

Tags: routing, proxy, socks, tor

Is there a way to redirect all traffic, UDP and TCP, coming to and from eth1 and eth2 through a SOCKS proxy (Tor) which then passes it through eth0?

eth0:
Internet in - leads to the main router, then the cable modem

eth1:
A USB Ethernet port setup as a modem (I think that's the word I'm looking for, right?)

eth2:
A USB WiFi antenna setup as a WiFi hotspot

Could I use something like iptables to directly route it through Tor or would I need an adapter like Privoxy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you need [tun2socks](https://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/tun2socks) (often a part of the 'badvpn' package). tun2socks sets up a virtual interface which you can route traffic through, and that traffic will get sent through the target socks proxy.

Setting it up gets a little tricky as you only want to route certain traffic through the tunnel.

This script *should* do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
socks_server=127.0.0.1:8080

id="$RANDOM"
tun="$(printf 'tun%04x' "$id")"
ip tuntap add dev $tun mode tun
ip link set $tun up
ip addr add 169.254.1.1/30 dev $tun
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.$tun.forwarding=1
ip rule add fwmark $id lookup $id
ip route add default via 169.254.1.2 table $id
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark $id
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i eth2 -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark $id
badvpn-tun2socks --tundev $tun --netif-ipaddr 169.254.1.2 --netif-netmask 255.255.255.252 --socks-server-addr $socks_server

iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -i eth2 -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark $id
iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark $id
ip route del default via 169.254.1.2 table $id
ip rule del from fwmark $id lookup $id
ip tuntap del dev $tun mode tun
```

---

#### Explanation:

```
socks_server=127.0.0.1:8080
```

This is the socks server we will use.

```
id="$RANDOM"
tun="$(printf 'tun%04x' "$id")"
```

These generate a random ID to use for the tunnel. Since you may have other tunnels on the system, we can't just use `tun0` or `tun1`. 99% of the time this will work fine. Adjust accordingly though.

```
ip tuntap add dev $tun mode tun
ip link set $tun up
ip addr add 169.254.1.1/30 dev $tun
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.$tun.forwarding=1
```

These set up the tunnel interface `tun2socks` will use.

```
ip rule add fwmark $id lookup $id
ip route add default via 169.254.1.2 table $id
```

These create a routing table with a single rule which sends any traffic with firewall mark `$id` (covered next) through the tunnel.

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark $id
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i eth2 -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark $id
```

These set firewall mark `$id` on any TCP packets coming in `eth1` or `eth2`. We only want to match TCP. Socks can't handle UDP or ICMP (tun2socks does have a way to forward UDP, but it's more complicated, and so I'm leaving it out).

```
badvpn-tun2socks --tundev $tun --netif-ipaddr 169.254.1.2 --netif-netmask 255.255.255.252 --socks-server-addr $socks_server
```

This starts tun2socks up. It'll sit in the foreground until terminated.

```
iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -i eth2 -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark $id
iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark $id
ip route del default via 169.254.1.2 table $id
ip rule del from fwmark $id lookup $id
ip tuntap del dev $tun mode tun
```

These tear down everything we created during the setup process. They will only run once `badvpn-tun2socks` exits.

Comment: Can I get a link to somewhere that explains how to do the UDP forwarding?

Comment: Official [tun2socks home page](http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/tun2socks), the UDP forwarding section.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ badvpn-tun2socks --tundev $tun --netif-ipaddr 169.254.1.2 \
    --netif-netmask 255.255.255.252 --socks-server-addr $socks_server \
    --udpgw-transparent-dns
```

**NOTE:** you must add `--udpgw-transparent-dns` for DNS request.