# redirect traffic of wlan0 through v2ray http proxy

Tags: debian, iptables, proxy

I have a Raspberry Pi with two interfaces.

- `eth0` is connected to router to internet.
- `wlan0` is acting as access point using hostapd and there is `udhcpd` service for `wlan0.`

I installed `v2raya` which connects to `v2ray` and creates socks proxy on port 20170 and http proxy on port 20171. I like to route wifi clients traffic through the `v2ray` proxy.

What should be the rules for `iptables`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by modifying the answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/144562/591860). I removed the parts for `eth2` and changed `eth1` to `wlan0`.